# Mongoose count embed array elements with aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongoose, count, aggregate

I'm currently trying to achieve something that would be trivial in SQL, but is really painful with Mongoose/MongoDb 3.3.

I have a collection of conversations. A conversation is started by an issuer and is made of zero or more messages. the messages are exchanged between the issuer and a user and are stored in a messages array. My chore is pretty easy, count the number of unread messages for a given issuer.

A single conversation for one issuer might read as follow :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578caba0264f76ec80d87e7c"),
    "issuer" : ObjectId("578c9c68261246f717343ab7"),
    "messages" : [
        {
            "content" : "Hi !",
            "type" : "text",
            "user" : ObjectId("56582b17b380912011c485e2"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("578caba08cf9a9081927e326"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-18T10:12:48.778Z"),
            "seenAt" : ISODate("2016-07-18T10:13:16.725Z")
        },
        {
            "content" : "Wassup ?",
            "type" : "text",
            "user" : ObjectId("569a9d343bd9840e26797412"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("578cabcb8cf9a9081927e327"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-18T10:13:31.254Z"),
            "seenAt" : ISODate("2016-07-18T10:13:34.133Z")
        },
        {
            "content" : "Fine, ya ?",
            "type" : "text",
            "user" : ObjectId("569a9d343bd9840e26797412"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("578cabd38cf9a9081927e328"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-18T10:13:39.573Z")
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far is use a Mongoose aggregation :

```
function findUnreadByIssuerId(issuerId) {
    return Conversation
    .aggregate()
    .match({ issuer: issuerId })
    .unwind('messages')
    .match({'messages.seenAt' : { $exists: 'false'} })
    .count()
    .exec();
}
```

The point here is that nodejs complains about count() not being a function. The aggregations seems otherwise ok, since if I remove the count() I get an array.

Then, I tried to use $group but I'm a newcomer to Mongo and its grouping and I'm getting an empty array :

```
return Conversation .aggregate([
    { $match: { issuer: issuerId } },
    { $unwind: '$messages' },
    { $match: {'messages.seenAt' : { $exists: 'false'} } },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$messages.createdAt',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
    ])
    .exec();
```

In the example provided, the expected result to the call would be 2 ideally. But I can handle a { sum: 2} although not ideal. What is wrong with my Mongoose aggregate chain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Mongo >= 3.4:

You should provide an argument to $count , which is the name of the column of the count .

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/

Use it like:

`.count("total_unseen")`

its not returning an integer but an object 
`{total_unseen: 1}`

> For Mongo < 3.4

Use $group and count:

```
{ $group: null, count: {$sum: 1} }
```

Regard the result:
If one of the stages in the pipeline is empty , the result will be empty, but usually the driver is casting into more proper value .

So for both method , when the count is 0 , the result will be empty array or null. (depends on the driver)

Comment: I need to stick with MongoDb 3.3. $count is available MongoDb 3.4 onwards. I update the question accordingly.

Comment: Two things puzzling me with your answer : the first one, the result is an array. The second one, if none of the message scontain a seenAt field, the result is [], not [{count:0}]. Any idea on how to get a consistent output ?

Comment: I ended up  chaining your Mongo <3.4 proposition's exec() call with a .then() and then format the response as I wanted it to be exposed. Thank you !